# Connect UISlider and UITextField to choose correct data - Simple calculator for loan installment

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uitextfield, uislider

As homework, I need to make simple calculator to calculate installments. I can't find and method to connect a `UISlider` and a `UITextField` to synchronize both to choose correct data.

I tried it, but it works for slider to textfield :

[image]

```
@IBAction func change(_ sender: Any) {
    TextField.text = String(Int(slider.value))  
}
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: To choose data on slider and display it on textfield, or to write in text field number and get slider on correct position :)

Comment: Sliders and text fields are both controls. Controls perform actions. So when the slider updates it value and posts its action, update the text field in the slider’s action method and vice versa. Right?

Comment: Right, but in one side i made it slider to text field, but in other i don't know how. Still have errors, can input number and set slider :/

Comment: Text field is a control too. You access its actions through the text fields delegate `UITextFieldDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

try use this, IBAction can be irritating at the beginning of learning

```
    override viedDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         addTarget()
    }

    func addTarget() {
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSliderChange), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    }


    //callback called when value change
    @objc func onSliderChange(){

        textField.text = String(Int(slider.value))
    }
```

Comment: Still can't input number into textfield :(

Comment: did you are using symulator ? if yes press command + K also try 
'someTextField.keyboardType = .decimalPad' witch allow you to push on textField numer value